# unknown as type function parameter

Tags: typescript

How do you oneline an unknown as Type function parameter?
E.g.

compilation error

```
React.useCallback((item: unknown as IEventRegistration) => {
    [...]
    }, []);
```

works

```
React.useCallback((item: unknown) => {
    const d = item as IEventRegistration;
    [...]
}, []);
```

Comment: Why use `unknown` at all? Why not `(item: IEventRegistration)`, so that the function gets typed properly?

Comment: The callback is called from a generic component. From the perspective of that component, it can be anything / unknown

Comment: Then you should type-test it inside the `useCallback` to check that it actually is the correct type, instead of simply assuming it is with `as`